# Specify merge parent in git

Tags: git, merge

I have merged two of my branches (using the Eclipse merge tool).

When I commit, the commit has only one of the branches as parents (the original workspace HEAD). I'll dig into why that happens later, but I need to commit this properly right now (there was lot of work involved in the merge).

How can i amend the commit to include the reference to the other branch? The file contents are all good now, I just want to have the commit have two parents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you have already committed, run `git reset --soft HEAD^` to undo it.

**Method 1**

Create `MERGE_HEAD` file in `GIT_DIR` (usually `/.git`) which contains `SHA-1` of the tip of the branch (you can get it using `git show-ref`) you are merging with (and an empty line, just to mimic `git merge` behavior). And commit as usual.

**Method 2**

Also, you can do it without messing with git internals, if you prefer:

- save copy of your working directory (without `.git` directory) somewhere
- do `git reset --hard`
- do `git merge branch_to_merge_with --no-commit`
- remove everything from working directory (except `.git` directory)
- restore working directory content from saved copy
- add changes & commit

P.S. it could happen if you've used `git merge --squash` option or `MERGE_HEAD` file was lost somehow.

Comment: I think I'll try method 1. Do I have to reset? Or can I use the amend option when committing?

Comment: Don't know if `commit --amend` can produce merge commit, I've never tried. But I'm sure that `reset --soft`, prepare `MERGE_HEAD` and simple `commit` should work.

Comment: Okay, that seems to have worked. I got a "corrupt MERGE_HEAD" first, but after I took out the extra empty line, it worked.